# Addhandler [process].Exited makes windows service to stop

Tags: vb.net, process

Recently I've created a windows service which can help to trace the process start time and exit time, but I found that whenever the addhandler [process].exited executed, the windows service will stop

Here are my codes for the handler

```vb
 For Each chrome_p As Process In NewChromeProccess
            chrome_p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            AddHandler chrome_p.Exited,
                Sub()
                    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\MonitoringApplication.txt", True)
                        ChromeEndTime.Add(chrome_p.ExitTime)
                        sw.WriteLine($"Process: {chrome_p.ProcessName}, Exit Time: {chrome_p.ExitTime}")
                    End Using
                End Sub

        Next
```

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source Service1 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Service cannot be started. An instance of the service is already running
```

Comment: Have tried putting in a simpler statement, perhaps log to event log, or a Debug.Print and using [Debug View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to see if it is the Handler or the code in the handler?

Comment: @JayV Hi, i have updated the event log problem can you help me check whether what problem is it?

Comment: What is the executable you are starting with this code? Is it a program with NO UI or a program WITH a UI? If it has a UI, this will not work as you expect. If you are using later versions of Windows the UI will not be started by a Windows Service

Comment: @JayV this is windows service code, whenever the process that i added the event handler triggered, the window service will write a exit time in the text file (this is working), but the window service will also automatically stopped. This program is without UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I think the problem you are encountering is due to the line

```
sw.WriteLine($"Process: {chrome_p.ProcessName}, Exit Time: {chrome_p.ExitTime}")
```

And, specifically, the `chrome_p.ProcessName` part. When I had the line as you wrote it above, I was getting the error message: `Process has exited, so the requested information is not available`. Switching that out with a string constant, I get the line `Process: chrome_p.ProcessName, Exit Time: 5/2/2019 8:05:46 PM` in the text log file.